# Align image and text differently inside HTML td

Tags: html-table, alignment, vertical-alignment

I have a table where the table cell (td) can contain both image and text. The cell height can be increased or decreased dynamically.

I want the image to be shown on top on the cell (always) and text in the center (always).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td><div>
      <img src="http://imgur.com/a/1s17J">
  </div>
  <div>
    Text
  </div></td>
  <td><div>
      <img src="http://imgur.com/a/1s17J">
  </div>
  <div>
    Text
  </div></td>
  <td><div>
      <img src="http://imgur.com/a/1s17J">
  </div>
  <div>
    Text
  </div></td>
  <td><div>
      <img src="http://imgur.com/a/1s17J">
  </div>
  <div>
    Text
  </div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
td img
{
  float:top;
}

td
{
  background-color:red;
  width:150px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maximelian/vesfLoj7/1/)

PS: please, provide some code because now I can just guess what did you meant by your request.

Answer (score 0):

use css
on img apply top:0px; float:left;
on td apply test-align: center